# Why is this javascript if condition not working as expected?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a comparison on dates in javascript. In this case date1 is empty `""` and I can see the same in firebug. As per the code below, the first alert shouldn't be called because `date1 == ""`, but for some reason the alert `alert(" This is called....");` is invoked. What is wrong here?

```
if(date1 != null || date1 != ""){

        if( (date1 != null || date2 != "") && (date1 < date2)){
                alert(" This is called....");
                break;
        }
        else{
            alert(" That is called....");
            break;
        }

    }
```

The above if condition is inside a for loop, hence the break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to be using `&&` instead of `||` in your first comparision to make sure that both conditions are true and I think you have typo where you're using `date1` instead of `date2` in the second test.  Further, you can just use `if (date1)` to simultaenously rule out `null` and `""` and `undefined` and `0` and `NaN` and any other `falsey` value.

I think you want something like this:

```
if (date1) {
    if(date2 && date1 < date2) {
        alert(" This is called....");
    } else {
        alert(" That is called....");
    }
    break;
}
```

If what you're really trying to do is make sure that `date1` and `date2` are legal numbers, then I'd suggest you do this:

```
if (typeof date1 == "number") {
    if(typeof date2 == "number" && date1 < date2) {
        alert(" This is called....");
    } else {
        alert(" That is called....");
    }
    break;
}
```

Or, if they're supposed to be Date objects, then you can test for that:

```
if (date1 instanceof Date) {
    if(date2 instanceof Date && date1 < date2) {
        alert(" This is called....");
    } else {
        alert(" That is called....");
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Let's say that date1 is a unix timestamp. Then if date1 is set to zero it means 1970-1-1. And your check for `if (date1)` may surprise the user. Don't shortcut the check unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @yankee - It is unclear what the type of the data is in `date1` and `date2`.   If the data is actually supposed to be numeric, I'd probably check to make sure it's numeric like `if (typeof date1 == "number")` rather than `if (date1)`.  I've added more info to my answer on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct to me. This statement evaluates to true because of the OR (||), since date1 is not null:

```
if(date1 != null || date1 != ""){
```

(it simplifies to `if (true || false) {` which is always true.

and the following statement evaluates to true as well because "" is not equal to null, and, presumably, date1 is less than date2:

```
if( (date1 != null || date2 != "") && (date1 < date2)){
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess someone else did -- seems pretty random to me. If I made a mistake, I'd love to know what it is, but a random downvote doesn't help anyone!!

Comment: @user918171: That would be a possibility, or you use and instead of or. Are you aware that `||` means OR and `&&` means AND?

Comment: if (date1 != null && date1 != "")

Comment: or I think you could actually just say: if (date1) {  but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest you this syntax

```
if(  (x==5) || (x==6)  || (x==7) || (x==8) )
```

this is best answer for checking `OR` condition using `JavaScript` and `JQuery`.

Comment: In the past, I tried as below and it always went to the ELSE part:

`if(x == (5 || 6))`

Answer (score 0):

> date1 is empty `""`

Look at this condition:

```
date1 != null || date1 != ""
```

`date1` **is** `!= null`, the second term (`date1 != ""`) isn't even evaluated because the first one passes - and the whole expressions evaluates to `true`.

Furthermore this condition:

```
date1 != null || date2 != ""
```

is also met (see above) - did you mean `date2 != null` this time? Nevertheless your `This is called` is displayed. BTW `break` has no sense in this context.

Finally you might consider simply:

```
if(date1) {
```

Not 1:1 equivalent, but pretty close.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that's a case where you should think about readability of your code. Here is my interpretation of your code:

```
if(!isBlank(date1){
    if(dateXIsSmallerThanDateY(date1, date2))
        alert(" This is called....");
    else
        alert(" That is called....");
}

function isBlank(date) {
    return date != null || date != "";
}

function dateXIsSmallerThanDateY(x,y) {
     return (x != null || y != "") && (x < y);
}
```

do you see a problem in dateXIsSmallerThanDateY? I can see one. What is that supposed to mean: `x != null || y != ""`? Probably it should read `y != null || y != ""`, which in turn can be shortend to `!isBlank(y)`.

Additionally the isBlank function does not check for beeing blank. Look what it does: It thinks that your date is blank if it is either *not* null or if it is *not* an empty string. Ok, maybe that is hard to read, so reverse this method:

```
function isNotBlank(date) {
    return date == null && date == "";
}
```

Positive comparisions are way easier to read. Do you see what is happening here? Can date be null and "" AT THE SAME TIME? No? Good. Than I guess you know what to do:

```
function isNotBlank(date) {
    return date != null && date != "";
}
```

Or in reverse:

```
function isBlank(date) {
    return date == null || date == "";
}
```